# Particles following ところ （に, を, and で）

Tags: grammar

> - 料理をしているところ**に**電話がかかってきて困った。
> - デートをしているところ**を**友だちに見られてしまった。
> - 電車に乗ったところ**で**今日は祝日だと気づいた。

In the above sentences, what decide the particle following ところ?  They all seem to indicate a happening during/while the user is engaged in an activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user4092 said, it is the verb that matters.

I will break down each sentence by explaining the verb.

## Sentences

1. > 料理をしているところに電話がかかってきて困った。

   `電話がかかってくる` accepts a number of things marked by に, and one of them is the time (compare: 「仕事中に電話がかかってきた。」).

   Thus, `料理をしているところ` in this first sentence is functioning as a time.
2. > デートをしているところを友だちに見られてしまった。

   Explaining this one is a little complicated since it's just a complicated sentence (using the adversarial passive), so you may want to come back to this after you know more Japanese, but anyways...

   <sub>**Necessary tangent:** 見られる is the passive of 見る. When you form a passive, you lift something from the underlying sentence to が, and the が-marked thing in the underlying sentence to に.</sub>

   <sub>In this case, the original sentence is 友達が［（私が）デートをしているところ］を見た, and the 私が gets promoted to the が-marked thing of the passive, and of course 友達 becomes the に-marked thing:</sub>

   > <sub>友達が　　　［（私が）デートをしているところ］を　　　　　　　　　見た</sub>
   >    <sub>⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓</sub>
   >    <sub>（私が）　　　　　　［デートをしているところ］を　　友達に　　見られた</sub>

   So, **the thing being marked by を is the thing being seen**.

   As such, `デートをしているところ` here is *not* behaving like a time as in (1), but instead as a noun referring to a past event.
3. > 電車に乗ったところで今日は祝日だと気づいた。

   Unlike (1), `気付く` doesn't accept times in the に position.

   So, instead, `電車に乗ったところ` here functions as a "location in time" where you did the realizing of `今日は祝日だ`.

   Compare, 「電車に乗った時点で今日は祝日だと気づいた。」, where 〜時点 is another "location in time" sort of thing.

## Summary

Basically, the complicated thing here is not ところ -- ところ is just flexible in terms of what it can behave as (time, location, noun) -- and that flexibility brings out the complexity of verbs in Japanese.

Being able to pick the right place to jam ところ with a verb more or less comes down having a good feeling for the verb and understanding what arguments it accepts.

Comment: With all due respect, I disagree with the notion that #3=location.  IMHO, both #1 & 3 are time.  #1 is "B happened while I was in the middle of doing A."  #3 is "I had no sooner done A than I did B."

Comment: @非回答者 I probably should have elaborated. The scare quotes around location were suppose to indicate that it's not literally a location. Similar to how "I stopped around where he waved his arms" can mean "I stopped around when he waved his arms", I think it's a "location-like thing" (syntactically speaking) which is standing for a past event. The alternative is for that で to be the copula, but that was not the sense I had at all. Do you think it's not even a location in the sense I'm describing here?

Comment: I tried editing in a little more about that. Let me know.

Comment: (Thank you for the very kindly-written comment, by the way!)

Comment: Could you give me more explanation of why 気付く doesn't accept times in the に position ? For example, 電車に乗った時に、今日は祝日だと気づいた I think it's possible to use (I'm just a beginner). Actually I can't make myself understand the concept of some verbs accept something (電話がかかってくる accepts a number of things marked by に, and one of them is the time) and (気付く doesn't accept times in the に position.).

Comment: @Kyuu This answer is mostly wrong TBH. #2 is right but l’electeur’s comment is the right way to understand the difference between #1 and #3.

Comment: I think the basic thing to understand is that で is essentially にて, i.e., に with a sense of ordering. ところに results in something happening at a specific time within the ところ interval, while で is more ‘immediately after’ the ところ interval.

Comment: 電車に乗ったところに今日は祝日だと気づいた seems to work grammatically but it’s odd semantically. I think I would mark it as ?.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks now I got it a lot. But could you explain this sentence "ふっとうしたところへとり肉を入れます"  (while it's boiling, put meat in it) I just wonder why is it not ところで -> put meat in as soon as it has boiled ? (#3 is "I had no sooner done A than I did B." ) I think it suits more

Comment: Hmm, I think AところでB requires some non volition regarding B, that the thing happens naturally or automatically, not as an intentional conscious decision based on A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 電車に乗ったところで今日は祝日だと気づいた I guess 気付いた here is non volition. Is it ?

Comment: That’s right. There’s no volition involved in realizing something.

Answer (score 0):

It's the verb that counts.

1. A phone call came to the part where I am cooking.
2. My friend witnessed the part where I am going out.
3. I noticed today was a holiday at the part where I got on the train.

Comment: While it is definitely the verb that counts, I don't think the English sentences are grammatical, so I'm not sure the parallel you're trying to draw is working.

Comment: Can this be explained in a simpler way?The above is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie The sentences are perfectly grammatical-- they're just nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

1. > *Just as / while* I was cooking, the phone rang.
2. > *While* I was in a date, I was seen by a friend.

However, をstress 「デートをしている」 as a direct complement, so literally, "the friend saw the fact I was in a date" .

3. > While on the train, I noticed that today was a day off.

で stresses place here.

---

If you want to understand them better as well as their translation, you should  check **subordinate sentences** regarding grammar.