# What is the purpose of "ところ" in this passage?

Tags: particles, syntax

The use of ところ is quite abstract to me sometimes, usually I can guess its purpose, but I'm not quite sure here;

> 「眼を耀かせてるところ悪…」

Does it act like a particle? Like it's defining what was in those eyes (evil shining in his eyes)?

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19173/5010