# ところ＋particle(助詞) precision

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, particles

Hy, I am currently working on with  新完成マスター N3 for my grammar part and I get stuck on a small section of the lesson related to ところ(~p.17)。

So far, I understand that, according to this lesson, ところ can be used to express something that just, will or be happening soon.

However, I do not get the point of the particles added after. I can understand why we would use *ところで/ ところだ*、but not why we would use *ところを/ ところへ*。

Here are the 2 sentences use as an example that I don't quite get the use f the particle:

1. ケーキができ上かった**ところへ**子供たちが帰ってきた。
2. 試験中、隣の人の答えをみている**ところを**先生に注意された。

Again, what role do those particles play exactly and how do they influence the sentence.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/does-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d%e3%82%92-always-mean-the-same-thing-as-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%ab-what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d%e3%81%b8?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you, it actually answers my question.