# What's で's meaning in this sentence

Tags: particle-で

> 最後の質問が解けたところで、試験終了のチャイムが鳴ったんだ。

What does で after ところ mean ?

Answer (score 6):

One of the definitions of ところで is 「時に（ときに）」 'at the time of ____', 'as _____ happens/happened'.

'As I solved the last question, the bell ending the test sounded.'

Comment: Thanks. But can I use ところに instead of ところで ？

Comment: @Kiw  This should answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18967

Comment: so I have just read it. Could I ask for the accurate information ? 1.I think ところで and ところに is interchangeable, isn't it ? 2. From the link, I'm not sure what is the difference between " Time " and " Location in time " ,but I think "Location in time " stresses that something occurs within an action. And  I think " Time " just implies that when an action being processed something occurs. Is that right ?                  Sorry if my sentences are vague.