# 「ところで／へ／を／です」 How does it work ? Help with an exercise

Tags: grammar

I'm currently studying the Shinkanzen Master N3 Grammar and during one of the exercise, I got an answer wrong which isn't such a big deal by itself, but unless I'm translating the phrase incorrectly.... I'm pretty sure I should have been right ?

The Shinkanzen indicates that "ところだ／です" is used to talk about "just before X happens" while "ところを" is used to talk about "while X is happening"

Now the exercise I got wrong was :

今、出かける準備をしている(　　)ちょっと待ってください

I translated it as "Please wait a bit while I prepare myself to go out" which means the proper answer would be ところを

But the answer sheet says it should be ところだから

And while I understand the から part, I don't understand why ところだ and not ところを

Can someone explain please ?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate? [Particles following ところ （に, を, and で）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18967/45489).

Comment: not really a duplicate, this post doesn't really answer my question =/

Comment: Exactly how is the question asked on the book? At least ところだから is not unique; obviously ところなので works as well.

Comment: It's written exactly as I put it here. We're given a sentence with a blank and 3 choices. In that case we had ところを、ところだから and ところで.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, ところを is usually translated as **although** or **even though normally...**

Which means if you use ところを:

> 今、出かける準備をしている**ところを**ちょっと待ってください

It would translate to something sort of like:

- Although I'm preparing to go out now, please wait a bit.

On the other hand, if you use だから

> 今、出かける準備をしているところ**だから**ちょっと待ってください

It would translate to:

- I am in the process of preparing to go out now, so please wait a bit.

In that sentence **ところ** is being used slightly differently; which makes ところ translate to "in the process of doing verb". Which means that verb+ている+ところ is already indicating an on-going action that is in the process towards completion. This is the "while" state you were referring to.

Using ところだから seems like it would be correct...

However, I would like to know if there is an answer key that provides an English translation for this fill-in-the-blank sentence. Without that, I'm not exactly sure what the end goal objective for this sentence's meaning is supposed to be.

Comment: I see, that would make sense indeed.
Sadly there isn't any translation given by the book =/

Comment: Alright, well pretty much if there is no context regarding how you should answer it, then I'm not sure how to help any further. I can say that either sentence is technically grammatically correct. Although, I will say that the one with だから sounds a lot more natural due to the nature of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Given your explication, だから does sounds better and more natural so I guess it's more of a linguistic difference between english and japanese, like a nuance we don't necessarily have in english. Thanks for your help !